# Check Printing via Visualforce PDF: Is it possible to display MICR code that uses E-13B font?

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I know that [Visualforce PDF rendering supports only a limited set of fonts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) so the answer to this question is most likely a resounding NO, but my Visualforce knowledge is somewhat dated or perhaps somehow has a fitting workaround, so asking the question out loud.

I am working on a check printing feature in Salesforce. I got most of the fields in place (see below), except the 'Clear Band' region at the very bottom (highlighted) where there is [MICR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) code that uses `E-13B` font to display some information relevant to the check (I am sure you have seen it).

Is it possible to somehow import that font and display it in my check PDF as opposed to the way I have it now (i.e. regular font)? Appreciate any helpful thoughts/workarounds.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that even if you use a MICR-compatible font, it won't be readable by a scanner, as the ink typically needs to be magnetic. These codes are typically manually added by encoders that work at the bank using dedicated 10-key machines and special ink ribbons. That said, you could use a static resource with the numbers (e.g. 1.gif, 2.gif, etc), and then "print" them out as a series of images:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!barcodeImages}" var="img"><img src="{!img}" /></apex:repeat>
```

At that point, the only thing you need to worry about visually is getting the padding just right so it conforms to the standard. However, like I said, this won't actually be readable by a "magnetic eye" scanner without getting special ink/toner for the actual printing process.

Comment: Ah! Precisely what I had in mind! I was hoping for a less ugly solution :-) But I guess this is it. I am not sure how we will deal with the magnetic stuff. That is a problem for a later time I guess. Thanks!